# How to edit image URL in node field?

Tags: 7, files, uri, media

I am using Media Browser widget for uploading and editing images in nodes. My images are stored using image fields. Is it possible to edit URL of the image after uploading? I would need to achieve:

When I upload file named "foo.png" it has by default the following URL:

> /sites/default/files/media/.../foo.png

I would need to edit filename to "bar.png", so resulted path will be:

> /sites/default/files/media/.../bar.png

(only filename is changed in URL)

I tried to edit filename, since it is possible using Media browser widget. But editing filename does not have affect on change of URL for me. I also tried to use following hook: [hook_file_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7.x)
I tried to programatically change uri parameter using this hook. But nor filename change neither uri change affected URL of the file. 
When I look in directory sites/default/files/..  I can see that filename is the same as I uploaded it, not affecting my later changes of filename or uri. When I load php $file object, I can see $file->filename and $file->uri properties changed.

Is it possible to change URL of the file (just last part of the URL - filename) after uploading the file?

//EDIT: I tried to do following changes in my hook_file_presave:

```
function mymodule_file_presave($file) {
 if ($file->type != 'image') {
  return;
  }
 if (!empty($file->filename)) {
   $uri_parts = explode('/', $file->uri);
   $count = count($uri_parts);
   $uri_parts[$count - 1] = $file->filename;
   $file->uri = implode('/', $uri_parts);
   $file->destination = $file->uri;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Use hook_insert()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename the file, you'll need to use PHP's [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function. To do so, you'll want to get the file's full local path using drupal_realpath() like so:

```
// Fetch the local absolute path of our image
$local_path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
```

Once you've renamed the file, you'll need to modify the file URI (and potentially other attributes-- use print_r($file) to check).

The wording in the docs is a little weird to me, it says ["when a file has been added to the database"](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7.x) which means to me the file metadata has already been saved to the database. However, the example shown in the docs seems to edit this info (but without using &$file ...?) without having to return the file object. Strange.

Anyway, your code might look something like this:

```
function mymodule_file_presave($file) {
  if ($file->type != 'image') {
    return;
  }
  if (!empty($file->filename)) {

    // Will likely be 'public://'
    $scheme = file_uri_scheme($file->uri);

    // Get full path of image location
    $local_path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);

    // Create new name using drupal scheme format
    $new_uri = $scheme.'new_name_here.jpg';

    // Actual OS rename of file
    rename($local_path, drupal_realpath($new_uri);

    // Update $file object with new uri
    $file->uri = $new_uri;

    // Not sure if this is still needed...
    $file->destination = $file->uri;
  }
}
```